# Run R (on Linux) interactively with a simple repl (no readline, no assumed terminal)

Tags: r, linux

I'd like to run R as an inferior process. I'd like R to display help pages as html (in the browser) and to display plots as if it were run interactively. I know I can run R with the `--interactive` argument but then R seems to assume it's running on a terminal end emit control sequences.

How should I run R to get html help pages & plot (as with `--interactive`) and simple textual output with no control sequences?

- If I use `R`, it assumes to be run non-interactively (html help pages or plots won't work but the output contains no control sequences).
- If I use `R --interactive --no-readline`, it runs interactively (help pages and plots work as expected) but the output is garbled and difficult to parse since it assumes to be running on a terminal.

Is there a way to control the assumptions R makes about the terminal it's running in?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that argument order matters. (Part of) the problem gets resolved when calling R as `R --no-readline --interactive`.